# Is CPT a unitary symmetry or an antiunitary symmetry?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, time-reversal-symmetry, cpt-symmetry, charge-conjugation

> Is CPT a unitary symmetry or an antiunitary symmetry, such as the free Dirac theory of fermion $\psi$ in Chapter 3 of Peskin's QFT book?

Since

- T is antiunitary symmetry,
- P is unitary symmetry,
- C is unitary symmetry,

then CPT is a combined symmetry, so should it be antiunitary?

Note that T symmetry changes $$\psi \to \gamma_1 \gamma_3 \psi(-t,x) \tag{1}$$ in Peskin's book, but should it have a complex conjugation $K$ such that the
$$\psi \to \gamma_1 \gamma_3 K \psi(-t,x)? \tag{1'} $$

All together, based on Peskin's book, CPT gives:
$$\psi \to \gamma_5 \psi^*(-t,-x)\tag{2}$$
but should the antiunitary T symmetry's complex conjugation $K$ join into the CPT transformation to give:
$$
\psi \to \gamma_5 K \psi^*(-t,-x)? \tag{2'}  
$$

> are equation (1) and (2) correct as Peskin's booh suggess? Or do we have in fact (1') and (2') instead?

> How is $\psi \to \gamma_5 K \psi^*(-t,-x)$ differed from  $\psi \to \gamma_5   \psi (-t,-x)$? Since $$K \psi^*(-t,-x)=\psi(-t,-x) \tag{3},$$ or what else could it be?

Comment: There is no complex conjugation when you perform time reversal on the bispinor field, i.e.  (1) is correct and (1') isn't. And yes, the $\mathbb{CPT}$ operator is anti-unitary.

Comment: @tomtom1-4 you can compare with Zee book eq.34 of p.104, Zee has a complex conjugation $K$ in it. So could you comment or write an answer again?

Comment: maybe related question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/667594/310987 maybe of some of your interests.

Comment: Related: [Time reversal and complex conjugation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/444494), and [Time reversal transformation of the complex scalar field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/445467)